How to extend styles of a reusable button component in Astro using class props
I'm working on a project using Astro and I'm trying to create a reusable button component that allows for extending styles using class props. My goal is to pass custom styles to the button while maintaining its default styles. Here’s what I have so far:
---
const {
  onClick = () => {},
  type = "button",
  variant = "primary",
  size = "md",
  class: className = "",
} = Astro.props;
---

<button
  type={type}
  onclick={onClick}
  class={`btn ${variant} ${size} ${className}`}>
  <slot />
</button>

<style>
  .btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2);
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .btn:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  /* Size variants */
  .btn.md {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .btn.lg {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  /* Color variants */
  .btn.primary {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: white;
  }

  .btn.primary:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-hover);
  }

  .btn.secondary {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    color: white;
  }

  .btn.secondary:hover {
    background-color: #var(--secondary-hover);
  }
</style>

 <Button variant="secondary" class="test" >example</Button>

<style>
    .test{
        background-color: red;
    }
<style/>

In this case the .test is not doing any effect
extend styles of a reusable button component

Did you notice that the last closing style tag has the slash at the end?

Great catch Markus

even with the correct closing style tag it doesn't do the exentend style

I've updated my answer added an example of your code working. I would suggest that you add a default class with CSS as you already did and use a variant or other prop to change the CSS styling. Passing a class won't work if you add it to an instance of a button.
---
const {
  onClick = () => {},
  type = "button",
  variant = "primary",
  size = "md",
  class: className = "",
} = Astro.props;
---

<button
  type={type}
  onclick={onClick}
  class={`btn ${variant} ${size} ${className}`}
>
  <slot />
</button>

<style>
  :root {
    --primary: rebeccapurple;
    --primary-hover: pink;
    --secondary: green;
    --secondary-hover: red;
  }
  .btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .btn:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
  }

  /* Size variants */
  .btn.md {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .btn.lg {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  /* Color variants */
  .btn.primary {
    background-color: var(--primary);
    color: white;
  }

  .btn.primary:hover {
    background-color: var(--primary-hover);
  }

  .btn.secondary {
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    color: white;
  }

  .btn.secondary:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary-hover);
  }
</style>

And then where you'd want the button use one of these:
 <Button variant="primary">Click me</Button>

 <Button variant="">Click me</Button>

 <Button variant="secondary">Example</Button>

